# why this jquery is not displaying the json response

Tags: jquery, html, json, api

I have a jquery script pulling a quote from an api and data is returned in json format. Then I'm trying to display the output to on page. But for some reason I'm not able to get data from the api. What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Qoute Machine</title>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){
    $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
  $("#quote").html(JSON.stringify(a.content + " " + a.title));
});
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Random Quotes!</h1>
<p>Press the button to display a quote!.</p>
  <button id="getMessage" type="button" onclick="getQuote();">Get quote</button>
  <p id="quote"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any errors in console ?

Comment: When you debug this, does `a` contain what you expect it to?  What does it contain?

Comment: Is this page inside origin (quotesondesign.com) ?

Comment: I'm trying to console.log(a.content) within my function, but nothing shows up... is console.log()  working within jquery? what would be a good way to log this to console, so I can see what I'm getting as result? by the way is this something that should be done through ajax or this can be done using jquery json object reques? thanks for the help

Comment: @miatech: Yes, `console.log()` works in JavaScript.  If nothing is logged for `a.content` then `a.content` contains nothing.

Comment: ok, I'm trying to troubleshoot this? so I guess the next step is to look at the api/url request... this is the url "http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1" and this is the documentation on this person's page... whenever I plug the url in the browser it will give output in the form of text... now the question is how should I parse the text? thanks

Comment: do I need web server functionality for this to work? Microsoft IIS or Apache? right now I'm doing this depending completely on browser functionality

Comment: ok, now I'm getting something back, but I'm getting same quote instead of random one. However, when I use url directly on browser it does randomize the quote.. what's wrong? thanks why this keeps returning the same quote, instead of a random one. when I use the url in the browser works... so what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`a` has already been parsed as JSON, so you don't need to stringify it to output two properties of `a` separated by a space. In fact, that's not even valid JSON.

You're trying to stringify non-JSON. Just use:

```
$("#quote").html(a.content + " " + a.title);
```

However, please note in the snippet below that there's a cross-origin issue with the request:

```js
$("#getMessage").on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
      $("#quote").html(a.content + " " + a.title);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Welcome to Random Quotes!</h1>
<p>Press the button to display a quote!.</p>
<button id="getMessage" type="button">Get quote</button>
<p id="quote"></p>
```

Comment: Is this something that should be done with ajax or json api in jquery? thanks

Answer (score 0):

it missing `});` at the end of code and you dont need `JSON.stringify` because `getJSON` return json or javascript object, also you don't need `onclick="getQuote();"` because it already handled by jQuery `$("#getMessage").on("click"`. the last if it accessed from different domain then you need to enable cross-origin (CORS)

demo, allowed CORS: https://jsfiddle.net/ng5ut2L5/1/

below, stackoverflow is not not allowed CORS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#getMessage").on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON("//quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
      $("#quote").html(a[0].content + " " + a[0].title);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Welcome to Random Quotes!</h1>
<p>Press the button to display a quote!.</p>
<button id="getMessage" type="button">Get quote</button>
<p id="quote"></p>
```

Comment: what browser? you can view it in action https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKzg1.gif

Comment: how did you get it? I've playing with this code and can't get this thing going. It can not be that difficult.

Comment: your link above.. it opens in jsfiddle however, it doesn't run. I know the gif image works. apparently the code runs just fine.